# How to weave through two chains

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I have two chains where lets say chain 1 has head, 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 and chain 2 had head, 5, 6, 7, 8. Weaving it should produce chain 1 with head, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8. My function is currently weaving, but only for the first 2 and it stops.

```
void Chain::weave(Chain & other) {     
 while (length_ > 0 && other.length_ > -1){
  Node * current = head_->next;
  Node * otherNode = other.head_->next;

  Node * currentNext = current->next;
  Node * currentPrev = current->prev;
  Node * otherNext = otherNode->next;
  Node * otherPrev = otherNode->prev;

  if (current != NULL && otherNode != NULL){
   current->next = otherNode;
   currentNext = otherNode->next;
   currentNext->next = otherNext;
   length_++;
   other.length_--;
```

}

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: This "weaving" is generally called "interlacing", though it's typically done in array data structures rather than doubly-linked lists. Perhaps that keyword should give you something to search for reference implementations.

Comment: You call it `current`, but you set it to `head_->next` every time through the loop. It never advances past the first node.

Comment: How would you reset it each time? Thats the problem I'm having. @IgorTandetnik